# javascript `require` instead of html `script` at three.js file in node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, three.js, browserify

I use javascript `require` instead of html `script` at three.js file in node.js.
a section of html file:

```
<script src="../build/three.js"></script>

<script src="js/controls/DragControls.js"></script>
<script src="js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="js/controls/TransformControls.js"></script>

<script src="js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
```

an equivalent section of javascript file:

```
var THREE = require('../build/three.js')

//module.exports = THREE

THREE.DragControls = require('./js/controls/DragControls.js')
THREE.OrbitControls = require('./js/controls/OrbitControls.js')
THREE.TransformControls = require('./js/controls/TransformControls.js')

var Stats = require('./js/libs/stats.min.js')
var dat = require('./js/libs/dat.gui.min.js')
```

so the `browserify` command show blank page in the browser.I think maybe the codes in javascript js file are not correct.so what should I do?

Comment: source is: 
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/webgl_geometry_spline_editor.html

Comment: did you try to open the [chrome developer-tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) to see if there is any error-message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with using browserify together with three.js is this:

- three.js uses the global variable `THREE` as it's namespace, when you `require('three')` (assuming you did `npm install three`), this global object will be returned, so `var THREE = require('three');` pretty much does what you'd expect.
- the three.js extensions mostly don't return (via `module.exports` if available) the Objects they defined, so in their case `THREE.OrbitControls = require('...')` will not do what you expect. Instead, they simply expect the global object `THREE` to exists and assign a new property to it. You will see a pattern of `THREE.OrbitControls = function() {...}` in these files.
- this doesn't work, because three.js (the main library) will not assign itself to the window-object if there is `module.exports` for it to use (you can easily test this, just add a `console.log(window.THREE)`.

To fix this, you just need to do this one step before loading the extensions, like this:

```
var THREE = require('three');

window.THREE = THREE;

require('./path/to/OrbitControls.js');
// ...

console.log(THREE.OrbitControls);
```

Comment: I did.show blank page.I use browserify a.js |indexhtmlify b.html    in gitshell.browse in chrome. No window no console.as source file its only drag and drop codes changing script HTML to require js format.I think the problem is with require codes.couldn't transfer data to the body.so what do you thinks?regards

Comment: please take a look at :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43582643/summerized-i-want-pure-js-file-in-node-js-render-phrase-in-three-js-javascript

and

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43568048/require-js-libs-stats-min-js-and-require-js-libs-dat-gui-min-js-phras

Regards

Comment: my problem solved.as I changed container.appendChild to document.body.appendChild   and use var Stats=require('./js/libs/stats.min.js');  and var dat=require('./js/libs/dat.gui.min.js')